# Solspace calendar next/prev month path

Tags: solspace-calendar

I am using Solspace month calendar. The calendar is embeded in another template. when I click on the next/prev month links it takes me to different page. I would like it to change the month but stay in the same page. It seems that there is problem with the path but I don't know how to fix it. I am using the following path:
**Previous Month**

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you're using the Calendar:Month tag or the Calendar:Cal tag in "Month" form, the adjustment will be different. If you're using the Calendar:Month tag, I would suggest switching to the Calendar:Cal approach, as it's far more flexible.

Have a look at the Advanced example:
http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/month/#advanced

In the header, just adjust the URI paths ({path='calendar/month'}) to match your actual URI in the code below:

```
<thead>
    <tr id="month_year">
        <th colspan="2">&laquo;
            <a href="{path='calendar/month'}/{prev_month format="%Y/%m"}/">
                {prev_month format="%F"}
            </a>
        </th>
        <th colspan="3">{date format="%F %Y"}</th>
        <th colspan="2">
            <a href="{path='calendar/month'}/{next_month format="%Y/%m"}/">
                {next_month format="%F"}
            </a>
            &raquo;
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Alternatively, if you wish to continue using the Calendar:Month tag approach, you can modify the source code (which will look VERY similar to the code above) here:
/themes/third_party/calendar/templates/month.html